# CoreData expects a string when returning an array and NSData when returning a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsvaluetransformer

I have a simple `NSValueTransformer` that should convert a comma-separated string `first, second, third` into an array. So in my CoreData schema I have the attribute `options` which I set to `Transformed` and specify my Transformer.

This is my Transformer:

```
-(id)transformedValue:(id)value{
    // convert it to an array
    if(!value){
        return nil;
    } else{
        NSString *languages = value;
        NSArray *result = [languages componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
        // return result;
        return @"test Result";
    }
}
```

Now when I return the variable `result` I get the following error (`length` looks like it's expecting an `NSString`):

```
... 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6cc59a0'
```

If I return the test string above instead I get this error (`bytes` looks like it's expecting an `NSData` object):

```
... 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf0780'
```

It looks like there is a conceptual problem which I don't seem to grasp. Also curiously `+(Class)transformedValueClass` and `+(BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation` are never "touched" when using the Debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no errors in code you provide. The problem lays in your CoreData approach.

When you use transformed property in CoreData, the value is storing in database as **NSData** object. And length in your errors is related to **NSData length** method.

Therefore you should provide NSValueTransformer with transformation from NSData to NSArray and reverse to put concatenated arrays to CoreData as NSData.

If you want to keep the possibility to store property as NSString, you can implement special accessor to NSString property of your managed object, which will transform the NSString to NSArray value or use your NSValueTransformer outside your CoreData model like this:

```
NSValueTransformer *transformer = [NSValueTransformer valueTransformerForName:@"StringToArrayValueTransformer"];
NSArray *array = [transformer transformedValue:yourEntityItem.yourStringProperty];
```

Comment: But couldn't I create a transformer that transforms the numbers from "one" to "ten" to numbers 1 - 10. Does it have to be NSData?

Comment: Take into account, that only Objective-C objects can be stored into CoreData. So there are no numbers except NSNumber, NSDate, NSString or NSData. I cannot understand your main goal to give you some piece of advice. But maybe you'd better add some additional object to your model and relation one-to-many to add some set of strings to your entity. It could be more elegant and effective solution.

Answer (score -1):

The value needs to be cast to a NSString try this

```
-(id)transformedValue:(id)value{
    // convert it to an array
    if(!value){
        return nil;
    } else{
        NSString *languages = (NSString*)value;
        NSArray *result = [languages componentsSeparatedByString: @", "];
        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: Negative, I still got the same error, also I have checked that the result is actually the array I was expecting in the debugger... I think `NSString *languages = value;` is an implicit cast, since languages is of the type NSString*.